# Marshall object field as attribute

Tags: jaxb

Here is what I have so far to marshall my POJO using JAXB :

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Local {
    private Entity entity;

    public void setEntity(Entity entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Entity getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }
}
```

and

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Entity {
    private String name;
    private String comment;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setComment...

    @XmlAttribute
    public void getComment...
}
```

With that, I get something like this:

```
<local>
    <entity name="" comment=""></entity>
</local>
```

However, I would prefer to have the name attribute as an attribute of the local:

```
<local entityName="" entityComment=""></local>
```

Is the XmlJavaTypeAdapter a good way to begin with?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Do you really need an Entity class?  If not, just put an @XmlAttribute on the String getEntity().

Comment: Yes, I need the Entity class as there are actually more than one attributes in the class. But yes indeed, if it was not the case, I would have done what you suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of different options to handle this use case:

**Option #1 - XmlAdapter (Any JAXB implementation)**

You could use an `XmlAdapter` for this use case.  This will work as long as only one attribute value comes from the `Entity` object:

***EntityAdapter***

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class EntityAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Entity>{

    @Override
    public String marshal(Entity entity) throws Exception {
        if(null == entity) {
            return null;
        }
        return entity.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Entity unmarshal(String name) throws Exception {
        Entity entity = new Entity();
        entity.setName(name);
        return entity;
    }

}
```

***Local***

The XmlAdapter is linked with the field/property using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
public class Local {
    private Entity entity;

    public void setEntity(Entity entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(EntityAdapter.class)
    public Entity getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }

}
```

***For More Information***

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html

---

**Option #2 - @XmlPath (EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**

Alternatively if you are using [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), the you could use the `@XmlPath` extension.  This is useful with the `Entity` object corresponds to multiple XML attributes:

***Local***

Specifying the XPath "." indicated that the child contents will be written into the parent element

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Local {
    private Entity entity;

    public void setEntity(Entity entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    @XmlPath(".")
    public Entity getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }
}
```

***Entity***

```
public class Entity {
    private String name;
    private String comment;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="entityName")
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment){
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="entityComment")
    public String getComment(){
        return this.comment;
    }
}
```

***For More Information***

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Yes it works ! And what if there are more than one attribute in Entity class and I want to have them all marshalled as attributes in the Local node. Then, I can't use @XmlAttribute on getEntity() method.

Comment: I added another attribute (comment) in Entity class to clarify my question.

Comment: @Alexandre Blanquart - This is where MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension (option #2) can be used to map your object model.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added the different artifacts described [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven) and the jaxb.properties file. I am able to define and compile your option but after deploying my J2EE ear to Glassfish, I am still seeing the default JAXB implementation. I followed your [article](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html), but I am wondering if I need to do something else to help glassfish to use MOXy.

Comment: @Alexandre Blanquart - You need to include the EclipseLink MOXy bundle in the `<GLASSFISH>/modules` directory.  This bundle must match the version of the other EclipseLink bundles (i.e. for GlassFish 3.1 this is EclipseLink 2.3.0).  This is touched on in the following blog post:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html