# Jax-ws Enum with multiple attributes

Tags: java, jax-ws, enumeration

I have a type class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="Record")
public class Record
{
    @XmlAttribute(name="status")
    private Status status  ;
}
```

and enum class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder={"status","error"})
@XmlEnum
public enum Status 
{
    OK(0, "No error"),
    ERROR(1, "Some error") ;

    @XmlAttribute(name="status", required=true)
    private Integer status ;
    @XmlAttribute(name="error", required=true) 
    private String error ;

    private Status(Integer status, String error)
    {
        this.status=status ;
        this.error=error ;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Status:" + this.status + " Error:" + this.error;
    }
}
```

The result I am getting is: Record status="OK"
but I want to have:  Record status="OK" error="No error"

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: If you're serializing type Record, and you want it to have two attributes, you'll need two attribute types in that record. It won't serialize two attributes from a single type defined to be one attribute (with one attribute name). Essentially your Record class needs to look more like your Status class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work the way you're expecting because JAXB gets the enumerations name rather than using the `toString()` method. But even if it did, it still would not produce the output you want. It would produce:

```
<record status="Status:0 Error:No error"/>
```

Using a normal JAXB there is no way to automatically expand a single field in to multiple XML attributes. The MOXy JAXB implementation does allow you to do this, but I doubt you're using this implementation (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246165/marshall-object-field-as-attribute) for more information.)

The least complicated solution is to just add another attribute containing the error message.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="Record")
public class Record
{
    @XmlAttribute(name="status")
    private Status status  ;

    @XmlAttribute(name="error")
    private String getError(){
        return status.getError();
    }
}

public enum Status 
{
    OK(0, "No error"),
    ERROR(1, "Some error") ;

    private Integer status ;
    private String error ;

    private Status(Integer status, String error)
    {
        this.status=status ;
        this.error=error ;
    }

    public String getError(){
        return this.error;
    }
}
```

Also, you don't actually need any of the JAXB annotations on the `Status` enum. The only time you need any at all is if you want the value printed in the XML to be different form the enumeration value (Like if you wanted the `OK` to appear as `ok` in the XML instead). See the @XmlEnum and @XmlEnumValue annotations [here](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_6_2_8-Annotations-for-Enums-XmlEnum-XmlEnumValue.html).

Comment: Oh, thx, lately I'm using only FIELD accessory types, and I forgot I can put element on a getter :)